# How in Typescript can I upgrade array of variable from class A to class B, which is extended from A?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript

hope it is not duplicate, but I could not find any question like that.

I have defined `Array<Tag>`, but I want it to be `Array<TogglableTag>`. `TogglableTag` class only differs by 1 more property, but what would be the cleanest approach to do this?

This is what I have from the beginning:

```
export class Tag {
    name:string
    count:number
    identificators:Array<string>

    constructor(name:string, count:number, identificators:Array<string>)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.identificators = identificators
    }
}
```

I made array from this so it is now `Array<Tag>`, this will be then `JSON.stringified` and stored.

But when should be restored, I need that one more property `isActivated` for each Tag

```
class TogglableTag extends Tag {
    isActivated:boolean = false;

    constructor (name:string, count:number, identificators:Array<string>) {
        super(name, count, identificators)
    }
}
```

My only idea is, that I shall loop through the whole `Array<Tag>` to push `new TogglableTag()` into empty `Array<TogglableTag>`.

Is not there something much more efficient?

Simply I just want to `Tag` class become `TogglableTag`. (for all array items) So the array entries will all have `isActivated = false`..

..Thank you for cooperation :)

Comment: I guess I'd ask: Is it really necessary to have that class distinction to begin with in your application? (i.e. why not put `isActivated` directly on `Tag`) Assuming you need to do something like persist `Tag` to a database, you could provide a serialisation method which knows to exclude `isActivated` when writing (i.e. because it's presumably a UI state only).

Comment: Yes, it is just for database, it is not nice to have there leftovers, which are only useful in live version.

Comment: Sorry for not so clear comment. It is rather opposite, so that I have `parser` which produces these `Tag`s and that `parser` of course wants to put it in `JSON`, but in the **same time**, there is also a preview of these `Tag`s, where there is **no need** for `isActivated`. **BUT** that `JSON` is also loaded somewhere else, where it should look like the same as in this *parser preview*, but it also must be clickable now, so I wanted these tags to automatically gain new property.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` have optional arguments for transforming the data when it's converted. Maybe you can use those options to omit `isActivated` from the stringify and then restore it on parse.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `Tag` and `TogglableTag` implementations are set in stone, then given an array of `Tag` objects:

```
declare const tagArray: Array<Tag>;
```

you can use its [`map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to produce an array of `TogglableTag` objects:

```
const togglableTagArray = tagArray.map(
    (tag: Tag) => new TogglableTag(tag.name, tag.count, tag.identificators)
);
```

---

Of course, if you can refactor so as to use lightweight [interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) instead of classes, like this,

```
interface Tag {
    name: string;
    count: number;
    identificators: Array<string>;
}

interface TogglableTag extends Tag {
    isActivated: boolean
}

declare const tagArray: Array<Tag>;
```

you can do the same thing but the mapping function can be achieved more simply with a spread:

```
const togglableTagArray = tagArray.map(
    (tag: Tag): TogglableTag => ({ ...tag, isActivated: false })
);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJEpeAGxCiiQBUQcDjSXRIAuJKAF02CyIsW8APYBXYN07AxYAEYQ0goSQwATCJIwAzDPBDcRaKJwCCaNCACeAHh58sAPiLKVo4PbHxDaABRsITnsMfgAaMnFJaVkFNHD1TW4dPQMjEyRzS1tg-kcASjxXFVJuAAsMKAA6AKQAXiQAgG4i4qQyisrRCW46iO7m5laSdqqErV19Hxp6saSJ1OMW0gBfItXCIooqGloRLCxKOXIIehwIAA9uTTUdhkLBoQrTbwwANwMINU45ERFjkGAvW0IHIUAgAyWJHcnm8Rn84ECXF4ISw4S6UQaMUU8Q04xSUzMFmsdmRuQKTCGpCgYhginhkDRkW4OMSyUmaTykKQ6xY6yKGi2aGQ0J63AYmWshKyNlOjghDxFbT2BxARxO4qJVl6YqwEqslTAIBgvi5vh1nFOBVqjgaEAA7nRlYdjqczQxqgjwjrOkyve7ZmyFlBOQ88gM+YQArAEMgAJKSRTAxD3IohK5oJPIU73VoBIKkrCNJBc9FSTHyRQDVoB+YEjKakkOOVrFwPNOJmOO-bO9VnS7XW6MLlPF7vK5fJA-P4QAEtjYPAWUIURDyijVZKXE2Xy4QiVdK7uql3r6zak-6w3G03mugMPIWp1H3t1G2+XBISqfnXxKDPJJjz5OGBUFkGWEMWDDVtliAA)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I give you upvote, but I cannot consider it as an answer, because my original idea was to loop through it, which is exactly, what map does. It is nice to see, how it works with spread operator, though. Thanks :)

Comment: If you need to copy n objects and add a property to each copy, then you’re not going to get something more efficient than O(n).  If you are okay with changing your data structure to make the copy unnecessary (e.g., give `Tag` an optional `isActivated` and have undefined mean false) then you can do that instead.  Do you have millions of these things where an O(n) solution is too slow or something? Or are you looking for an answer like “no, looping is no slower than any other solution”?

Comment: Looping should not be such a burden, as there may be up to 100 tags at max.

But somehow I naively expect, there still may be another answer.

I can imagine, that property `isActivated` could just appear automatically, when it is accessed first time.

Something like: 'Ok we have that `Tag` here, it has initialized all its properties, but it is now `TogglableTag` and we are accesing yet uninitialized property `isActivated`, so now we initialize it with value `false` right, when we use it.

Comment: Why don't you just use `TogglableTag` and not `Tag` then?  What do you gain from having two separate classes with different behaviors?  As soon as you have two different classes you will need to convert one to the other, and if you do it for n objects you have an O(n) algorithm no matter how you do it.  You *could* have one class that only initializes `isActivated` to `false` the first time it's accessed, but this would involve getters or Proxies and would be so heavyweight compared to just initializing a boolean property that I can't imagine preferring that solution.

Comment: If `isActivated` were some really expensive operation like querying external data or performing a long calculation, then setting up the class to only evaluate it on first access would be plausible.  But `this.isActivated = false` is so fast as to be negligible. It's not worth it. Take a step back and figure out exactly what you're trying to optimize and why. Keep in mind that humans are not so great at anticipating which parts of their code will need optimization, which is why profiling is useful. 100 objects with a boolean is going to be cheap no matter what, so maybe stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

@miqh raises some good points.  There is room to improve your structure.

But to address the mapping issue, all you need to do is:

```
const togglable = array.map(tag => new TogglableTag(tag.name, tag.count, tag.identificators))
```

You could rewrite your constructors so that they take a a single argument which is a props object and that makes mapping from one to the other much easier because both classes implement the props interface, so you can pass a `Tag` or `TogglableTag` instance directly into the constructor.  You don't even need to know which it is.

```
const tags: (Tag | TogglableTag)[] = []

const togglable = tags.map( tag => new TogglableTag(tag) );

const nonTogglable = tags.map( tag => new Tag(tag) );
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwOYAUoHsAOAzsgN4CwAUMtciHALYQBchYUoGlNyCuAruCYg%209AEbQuNYABMI4YDGAI4YXFEJMAglChwAngB5W7EBgB8lAL6VKEAB741YHgBs4hYugzJg9fC4hGcE9MHAJicioaOkYWNg5Jal4BMCERcShEn1l5RWVVdS0dfSN40wsKLN4QYz4EAoAKfDwiJjRQlsIASizI7m4wAAtgQgA6GJQAXmRm8PGGCABuLIHhseTwZGnZolGNsGWo-uQhkdGZOTAFJRU1Ym3O85yrvNv1LOsKT8oENw80XAYDBuUQBLzIeyQEDSELeXz%20QKXWFhIikLIjTT1YAANxUEGkTFEuFwATgIC2yHgLkISysNgo1VYJ0wGmQDXBAB8AUCQWDMF0ANoAXQpwvpjOcqh5cFBU2ZGDG9Dg%20Aa8q2ZloEAA7tzgTK%20RgGmB%20cguocfrgas4QJbUIC9bKKcaFaMlSq1ZMNSBte1Dc6uqbFkA)

Or you can keep your current constructor and add a static `fromTag` method as an additional way to construct.  Then you can map like this:

```
const toggleable = tags.map( TogglableTag.fromProps );

const nonToggleable = tags.map( Tag.fromProps );
```

With the caveat being, I can't figure out the right syntax to deal with the inheritance, so I had to put the method separately in both classes to get it to work. (dumb and bad code)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwOYAUoHsAOAzsgN4CwAUMtciHALYQBchYUoGlNyCuAruCYg+9AEbQuNYABMI4YDGAI4YXFEJMAglChwAngB5W7EBgB8lAL6VKEAB741YHgBs4hYugzJg9fC4hGcE9MHAJicioaOkYWNg5Jal4BMCERcShEn1l5RWVVdS0dfSN40wsKLN4QYz4EAoAKGOZjDgAaHn5BYTFoDpk5MAUlFTUNbV1DVvKASizI7m4wAAtgQgA6ZuQAXloGCABuLKXVjeTwHc6Uo6jF5BW19YHckYLiXeehvNH1LOtK27IVgqJTIGB4ehhIgNfB4IhMNChOGEGakY40KAQMB8KAgWgQADu91ODWQsPCm32HXJRHW5zA1ORTxyX1eY2QMxu3H+-0oCDcHjQuAwGDcogCXmQ9kgIGkIW8vn8gUG8qhESya009WAADcVBBpExRLhcAE4HjdvAXIRDjZAdVavU1Mgmvs4iYMB16WlelB+izhvkxkVJqUPWZUQs7kC+PhoK7GF6ugzsoNAz8UX87dxgUMEGCIWqYciEV41ZH0dRMdjcfiiQ9CKSaRtmoyKfS27TPum3hyuTQeXaHc4wJgNC7JQAfIUisUSzAzADaAF1Liuh7gaiPhaKIHBxShdqOMBt6HB8KTUDu5xAvOtwbhIci+xut7RN1fZ3uD5dj6fz5emD3oWz6cq+rDIGeADWt7Xt+ASXKSf6lpgK4cqW177vOGBodsZj3GO6xnheM6ilht5AQ+T7hC+ALDpBcAwQAch+cHkYhBEnhhs7kV4aEzChOGrnhnH-iRd5UWqtF8puEFwMUeiCbhyArjc9GqDxP67PJkxEQBx47PhICEqRN5eA0x6UomnF0smHSWd23xvDMnJAA)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I give you upvote, but I cannot consider it as an answer, because my original idea was to loop through it, which is exactly, what map does. However I like the idea of using a single object for Tag constructor, so it can be simply used for creation of new TogglableTag. Thanks :)